# Filter not working in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple data receiving from firebase but filter not works on that data.
I have searched lot of posts but nothing helps. 
What am missing .? any help

i can able to achieve the same like data if its inside OnInit().
below is my code:

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
ngOnInit() {
const someEvemnts = [
{type: 'attack', value: 1, target: 'dorkman'},
{type: 'yaeed', value: 2, target: 'dorkman'},
{type: 'attack', value: 3, target: 'fluffy'},
{type: 'attack', value: 4, target: 'dorkman'},
]
const total = someEvemnts
 .filter(event => event.type== 'attack')
 .filter(event => event.target== 'dorkman')
console.log(total); // works fine 

let check = this.values; // works fine 
let check2 = this.values.filter(val => val) // not works 
console.log(check);
console.log(check2); // returns empty
this.SignIn();
}

SignIn(){
  firebase.database().ref('/companies').on('child_added', (data)=>{
      this.values.push(data.val())
  }
  )
}
values=[];
}
```

Console:

[image: console].

Answer (score 1):

It's doesn't works because you call this.SignIn(); to populate the "Values" variable after you call the console.log. So, when you do console, the "Values" has empty.

Execute the "console.log" after the variable is popular.

Try this:

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
ngOnInit() {
const someEvemnts = [
{type: 'attack', value: 1, target: 'dorkman'},
{type: 'yaeed', value: 2, target: 'dorkman'},
{type: 'attack', value: 3, target: 'fluffy'},
{type: 'attack', value: 4, target: 'dorkman'},
]
const total = someEvemnts
 .filter(event => event.type== 'attack')
 .filter(event => event.target== 'dorkman')
console.log(total); // works fine 

this.SignIn();
}

SignIn(){
  firebase.database().ref('/companies').on('child_added', (data)=>{
      this.values.push(data.val())

      let check = this.values; // works fine 
      let check2 = this.values.filter(val => val) // not works 
      console.log(check);
      console.log(check2); // returns empty
  }
  )
}
values=[];
}
```

Comment: Correct either put it in the respond of the database or it can be filtered after with an html event which will trigger a different function.

Comment: but first i want to push data to values, then only i want to access that data.

Answer (score 0):

```
let check2 = this.values.filter(val => val) // not works
```

It can't work if you dont do a expression like

```
let check2 = this.values.filter(val => val.isAwesome)
```

What do you want to filter? If you wanna filter string, you do like:

```
let check2 = this.values.filter(val => val.label === 'hello')
```

Comment: thats what am trying to acheive but that is not working as expectd

Comment: which variable you wanna filter? you don't have a boolean in your data. Your code filters for the whole object, which can't be filtered and so it's returning nothing.

Comment: let check2 = this.values.filter(val => val.name == 'shanth')